# Same thread for multiple requests from the same browser in Tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

I'm new to servlets and I noticed that multiple requests from the same browser (different browser tabs) is resulting in the same thread. I know that threads are allocated from a thread pool and I thought this could be a coincidence but after several tries I'm still seeing the same result.

Here is the code I'm using in Tomcat 7.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    System.out.println("Current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -- Session ID: " + session.getId());
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    System.out.println("Current thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " -- done ...");
    response.getWriter().println("Hello");
}
```

Here is the output after sending 2 requests from 2 tabs in the same browser. The time difference between generating the 2 requests is less than a second.

```
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-54 -- Session ID: A74D21132DDED8F35280117E8040CD72
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-54 -- done ...
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-54 -- Session ID: A74D21132DDED8F35280117E8040CD72
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-54 -- done ...
```

But when the requests are sent from different browsers, I'm getting the desired result.

```
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-57 -- Session ID:  A74D21132DDED8F35280117E8040CD72
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-55 -- Session ID: 7BE3E5007F49A8301BE792B10E665D75
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-57 -- done ...
Current thread: http-bio-8080-exec-55 -- done ...
```

Is thread per session the default behavior in Tomcat? Is there any way to get different threads for multiple requests from the same browser in Tomcat? I'm testing synchronize on session logic.

Comment: Your second example is not comparable to the first one as it seems the requests are overlapping - so the first is not done yet when the second request 'arrives' hence tomcat has no other option than starting a second thread. Apart form that, re-using thread is totally legal and usually also no problem at all.

Comment: It you really want to test concurrency of your web application, you should use test automation, e.g. JMeter can create as many parallel requests as you want. (http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Comment: You assume your browser uses 2 connections for 2 tabs, which it does not. Your browser re-uses any available connection ("keep-alive") for any request to the same host, unless you explicitly forbid it (e.g. press ctrl-F5 in FireFox). So write or use a proper test-client (curl?) that opens and closes connections as you would expect.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get the desired behavior by opening 2 windows of the same browser and pressing  ctrl-F5.